# cannot find symbol class ModelAttribute

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I've got such methods in controller

```
@ModelAttribute("registerForm")
public RegisterForm getRegisterForm() {
    return new RegisterForm();
}

@RequestMapping("/registration.html")
@ResponseBody
public String registration(
        @ModelAttribute("registerForm") @Valid RegisterForm form,
        BindingResult result) {

    validator.validate(form, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("ERRORS WAS FOUND");
    } else {
        logger.debug("NO ERRORS!");
    }

    return null;
}
```

But when I do `mvn package` I've got compilation error - `cannot find symbol`

In pom.xml I've got spring dependecies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and `javax.validation`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the actual error message (which symbol can't it find?)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott well actually the issue was solved after `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and import libraries in code manually. So the case is closed.

Comment: So you solved your own problem within 6 minutes of posting your question on SO? I assume you're just sharing to help others...?

Comment: @CodeChimp -- I'm not sure anyone benefits from eclipse :)